# Skipping a gson field in parent class on selected execution

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have two classes with GSON implementation in this scenario, one is A and other is B,

```
Class A {

    @SerializedName("x")
    @Expose
    private String x;
    @SerializedName("y")
    @Expose
    private String y;
 ...
} 

class B extends A{

    @SerializedName("x")
    @Expose
    private List<String> x;
    @SerializedName("z")
    @Expose
    private String z;
...
}
```

Problem is both classes need to have the serialized name x field in there and can not do any changes to class A since that is used by some other classes, So when class B is serializing it gives and error due to multiple variable in one serialized name. What will be the optimal solution for this? GSON Exclusion Strategies will not work as per my understanding coz it will skip the parent x always.

Comment: Can you also add your getters because I think you can't have `public List<String> getX()` in class B, also which x do you want to serialize in your JSON when you serialize B? A.x or B.x?

Comment: @Bentaye, I want to serialize the B.x

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an `ExclusionStrategy` when serialising `B`, but not when serialising `A`. So just make 2 `Gson` objects.

**ExclusionStrategy**

This will ignore `A.x` when used.

```
class MyExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

  public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    return false;
  }

  public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
    return field.getDeclaringClass().equals(A.class) && 
           field.getName().equals("x");
  }
}
```

Given these 2 objects:

```
A a = new A();
a.setX("xValue");
a.setY("yValue");
```

and

```
B b = new B();
b.setX(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
b.setY("yValue");
b.setZ("zValue");
```

**Serialise `a`**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String aAsJsonString = gson.toJson(a);
System.out.println(aAsJsonString);
```

Outputs:

```
{"x":"xValue","y":"yValue"}
```

**Serialise `b`**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setExclusionStrategies(new MyExclusionStrategy())
    .create();
String bAsJsonString = gson.toJson(b);
System.out.println(bAsJsonString);
```

Outputs:

```
{"x":["a","b"],"z":"zValue","y":"yValue"}
```